# Can all NMR spectrometers perform special techniques such as COSY, NOESY, HETCOR,..?

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

Do you need special spectrometers for:

- probing nuclei other than hydrogen or carbon?
- performing 2D spectroscopy such as COSY, NOESY, HETCOR, HSQC,..

Or are these techniques usually available on standard NMR spectrometers?

Comment: Can you give a bit of a background for this question? It would seem strange that you don´t know the answers (or have an expert at hand to ask) if you know these techniques and are thinking about using them.

Comment: What do you consider a standard NMR spectrometer? Could you be more specific (it depends on the probe in the instrument, e.g. triple resonance probe)?

Comment: @Karl I agree with you that the question _as such_ rises indeed the (meta) question about the background of the OP.  On the other hand, there is a wide spectrum (no pun intended) of groups.  Some still drop the NMR tube in a card-board box and basically await the spectrum to be physically printed; others _expect_ each member pass an introduction and then to record 1D/2D, Hoye's no-D and kinetic NMR on their own.  Speculation: _maybe_ the OP transients to such a later group.

Comment: @Buttonwood Of course, it´d just be good to *know* about that, to give an answer that actually fits. I hate preparing a talk for an unknown auditorium. ;)

Comment: @Karl I aggree.

Comment: @Karl: however, keep in mind that here on sx people with other background may end up reading/being refered to this question as well.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I´d much rather serve one kind of reader properly. My thing below seems to be liked, but it´s a quick stab in the dark, not a profound answer.

Comment: @Karl: that's fine, and my comment is really only a comment. As a vibrational spectroscopist who's never really had anything to do with NMR (outside the 1d 1H and maybe 13 C student practicum level, that is), your answer reads understandable to me, so IMHO it *is* written for a sufficiently broad audience. I'll delete both comments soon in order to declutter.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on *a lot* of things, software-wise

- some of these techniques are simply a software option
- you can implement pulse sequences yourself, if that´s possible with your control software
- you need to have the right software to transform and evaluate the data
- ... or write it yourself (not exactly rocket science if you know your way with Matlab/Octave etc.)

and also regarding your hardware

- you can have several probes for one spectrometer

  - they can be single channel, or dual ("HX" usually), triple ... channel
  - the "X" channel can be tuneable over a wide(r) range, or you are limited to e.g. carbon
- of course you need a transceiver with enough channels, which can be used at the wanted frequencies
- and a suitable preamp for every channel
- some techniques need more special hardware, like CPMAS, pulsed gradients, cryo etc.
- low field spectrometers on the market (afaik) have no user exchangable parts, so you are stuck with the hardware you bought

But to answer your immediate question: I guess with basically any living (as in "not undead") spectrometer, all those you named above should be possible, provided you can tune the X channel to the het nucleus you are after. They are the basic standards.

If you want to know a lot more, [*200 and More NMR Experiments*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/200+and+More+NMR+Experiments%3A+A+Practical+Course-p-9783527310678) by Berger and Braun is probably your book.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple aspects to consider here.

- In terms of *the magnet*, the ones suitable to record a $300$ or $500\, \pu{MHz}$ $\ce{^1H}$ NMR spectrum may be well used to record 1D or 2D homo- and heteronuclear spectra as well.
- Other nuclei than $\ce{^1H}$ or $\ce{^{13}C}$ routinely are recorded in 1D with these standard spectrometers as well; for example $\ce{^{15}N}$, $\ce{^{19}F}$, $\ce{^{31}P}$ often relevant in samples equally relevant for biochemistry (heterocyclic chemistry, proteins); or inorganic chemistry (e.g., $\ce{^{117}Sn}$, $\ce{^{119}Sn}$, $\ce{^{195}Pt}$).
- Recording spectra with nuclei other than H and C however *often* is performed with dedicated probeheads. As an example, you are used that DEPT-135 / DEPT-Q / APT spectra are recorded to seemingly yield singlet signals only by proton broadband decoupling.  A standard two-channel probehead however is not designed to equally decouple $\ce{^{19}F}$ beside $\ce{^{1}H}$, for example, and consequently your 1D $\ce{^{13}C}$ spectrum still show the couplings with $\ce{^{19}F}$:

  [image]

  ([source](https://u-of-o-nmr-facility.blogspot.com/search/label/13C-19F%2020coupling))

  An other example is recording NMR spectra for three types nuclei *at once* by *triple resonance* with three scales, as seen in biochemistry to elucidate protein structures. (An entry to this vaste topic might be Wuethrich's Nobel lecture 2002, [here](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/chemistry/2002/wuthrich/lecture/).)

  [image]

  ([source](https://www.protein-nmr.org.uk/solution-nmr/assignment-theory/visualising-3d-spectra/))

  Displaying only the mount of the heads still visible on the bottom of the NMR magnet, this would not be possible with a standard probehead:
  [image]

  ([source](https://www.uwyo.edu/chemistry/instrumentation/nmr/nmr-probes.html))

  but would recorded comfortably with a triple-resonance head like this
  [image]

  ([source](https://www.ebay.com/itm/BRUKER-500MHz-5mm-NMR-Probe-with-Gradients-Nuclear-Magnetic-Resonance/232806178548?_trkparms=aid%3D1110001%26algo%3DSPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D20160323102634%26meid%3D04a617733030407bb0394876833349e6%26pid%3D100623%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D183622269613%26itm%3D232806178548%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675&_trksid=p2047675.c100623.m-1))
- Recording NMR spectra requires adjustment of pulse sequences (e.g., delay times and phases). Typical parameters are literature known (e.g. [APT for $\ce{^{13}C}$](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2364(82)90105-6) in the [*Journal of Magnetic Resonance*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-magnetic-resonance)), so the software of the spectrometer may internally look up and adjust thes for the more frequently used ones experiments.  Occasionally, you find blogs about these techniques, too (e.g., [University of Ottawa](https://u-of-o-nmr-facility.blogspot.com/), [PNA](https://www.process-nmr.com/blog/))

Comment: Can you check the first sentence in your last point, I can´t make head or tail of it. ;)

Comment: @Karl Indeed, the phrase required an edit.